# Can you run R scripts in Javascript offline?

Tags: javascript, r

I want to create a Javascript-based program that runs R scripts, and I've learned R-Node is one of the possible options. However it seems like it's web-based and that it's not a library I can have locally.

Is there a library available to help run these R scripts, using Javascript and offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure if this is what you're after but:

1) You could run R-node in a browser whilst offline, using node-js to serve the files (most browsers will work without a local webserver also)

2) If you have R installed, you can use node-js to execute R scripts:
   see: http://contourline.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/700/